# Weird numbers from top command

Tags: cpu-usage, top

I searched a lot on Google about my problem and found some interesting responses (many of them on SuperUser itself) but nothing that could explain what is happening to me.

I wanted to check the CPU usage of a system based on a Freescale i.MX6 Quad/DualLite (ARMv7 CPU with 4 cores)  when an application I developed is running on top of it.

I launched the application and then **top** in order to monitor the CPU usage: the result is that the CPU time of my application is higher than the system total.

[image]

I noticed that Irix mode was ON so I disabled it in order to get the percentage compared to 4 cores but numbers still seem weird to me.

[image]

22% divided by 4 is exactly 5.5% (that is expected) but then why looking at Idle time (third line of **top** output) it is 99.7%? That should imply that the overall CPU usage is 100% - 99.7% = 0.3%.

Am I doing something wrong with the math?